# C# Regular Expression - How to identify full name from the first 3 letters of each name

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using regex `Mar(.*)Ant(.*)Ara[^\s]*\s` to locate names in PDF file pages, an example of the result is:

**Mar**ck SC. **Ant**ony L. **Ara**gon
**Mar**cus **Ant**hilope Burton Chase **Ara**ujo

But the use of `(.*)` will return any text of the entire page, including texts that are not full names.

How can I prevent this regex find very long text (which is not a name) but who answered the regex? Example:

Return wrong:

*And the Cat* **Mar**ked this on looking at **Ant**i-terror panel in the city of **Ara**gon

Following the same principle thought to improve this regex **forcing the reading to 10 words** (from the first name) and not entire page.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a range quantifier `{min,max}`

```
@"\b(Mar\S*)(?:\s+\S+){0,3}\s*\b(Ant\S*)(?:\s+\S+){0,3}\s*\b(Ara\S*)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO6zT2/8)

`(?:\s+\S+){0,3}` - `\s+` matches one or more space and `\S+` matches one or more spaces, then the whole pattern would be repeated from 0 upto three times.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mar[^ ]*(?:[ ][A-Z][^\s]*)* Ant[^ ]*(?:[ ][A-Z][^\s]*)* Ara[^\s]*
```

Make use of the fact that names will start from `capital letter`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/3